# \usepackage{geometry} not working with \maketitle

Tags: geometry

Have an odd (as in 'weird', not measurement) size printing requirement, and using the \geometry package to create the new page size.  The problem is that \maketitle is creating a default US-Letter first page (the title page), and only then does the new size kick-in; all the remaining pages are properly sized.

I've found multiple solutions for changing the paper geometry mid-document, but nothing addresses the default 'first page' or 'title page' size.

Thanks in advance.

Here's an example:

```
% vim:ft=tex:fo+=cont:fo-=a


\documentclass[10pt]{book} 


%\usepackage {hyph-utf8}
\usepackage[papersize={7in,7in}] {geometry}
\usepackage {booktabs}
\usepackage {cite}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage {wrapfig}
\usepackage {xltxtra}
\usepackage {xunicode}
\usepackage {makeidx}


\title{Bad cover page}
\date{\today}   % '\today' will keep printed revisions in order

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Limits the depth of the Table of Contents

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

%\include {./preface}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}


This is a test document.  
Cover page renders as US Letter.
Remainder is 7x7 inches square.

%   Insert blank page at the end for, say, notes or something.
\clearpage

%\bibliography{Bibtex.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a small, compilable example document to your question that can be used to reproduce the problem you encounter.

Comment: Revised OP; added example doc.

Comment: please make sure the MWE is self contained. This one is referring to files we do not have access to.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  Thought I got all the \include's when I posted.

Comment: I just compile the code in overleaf and I don't see any problem with paper size

Comment: So good of you to let us know that service works with my file.  But I'm still having difficulty with the regular TeX compiler on the local box.